# How to distinguish between "unset" and "no-assignment" for NULL values?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, php-7.1

In php in this example – but in general programming actually, is there a way distinguish between a *"no-assignment"* and *"unset-value"* command for `null` values when merging 2 immutable data objects of the same type?

Consider this php class that is an immutable data object. It takes a string and an integer in its constructor, and only provides accessors for the values:

```
class Data
{
    protected $someNumber;
    protected $someString;

    public function __construct(?int $someNumber, ?string $someString)
    {
        $this->someNumber = $someNumber;
        $this->someString = $someString;
    }

    public function getSomeNumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->someNumber;
    }

    public function getSomeString(): ?string
    {
        return $this->someString;
    }
}
```

The values can be either `null` or their respective datatypes `string` or `integer` at all times. Also the constructor accepts `null` values instead of `string` and / or `int`: the UNSET operation.

Now I want to be able to merge 2 instances of `Data`, something like this simplified factory method that accepts `$first` and `$second`, where data in `$second` overrides data in `$first`, if present.

```
class DataFactory
{
    public function merge(Data $first, Data $second): Data
    {
        // Uses data from $first if corresponding data from
        // $second is (strictly) null
        return new Data(
            $second->getSomeNumber() ?? $first->getSomeNumber(),
            $second->getSomeString() ?? $first->getSomeString(),
    }
}
```

In the above example, `null` values returned by the accessors of `$second` are interpreted as NO UPDATE operation: when `null` is encountered the corresponding value of `$first` is kept. The problem is that I want to be able to distinguish between a request for either a NO UPDATE operation or an UNSET operation within `merge`.

The strict typing in the `Data` class disallows the use of some sort of string constant like `"DATA_UNSET_FIELD"` as a value to flag, so implementing this directly on the data itself seems impossible. More so even because passing the constructor null for any value should definitely mean SET NULL.

I am thinking about some sort of update lens that explicitly specifies the properties that should be UNSET when merging, so that `null` values in `$second` would simply mean NO UPDATE (keep from `$first`).

What would be a compact object oriented pattern to solve this? I can already imagine problems like exploding plain array schemas or a class explosion of strategy classes as data grows. Also I'm slightly concerned about the "mobility" of `Data` objects as new objects have to be associated with them at some point.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**

I'd like to be able to differentiate between *not overriding* a current value and *unsetting* a value – i.e. assigning `null` – when merging 2 instances of `Data`, where `$first` is the base, and `$second` overrides data of `$first`. As a detail, merging results in a third, new object that is the merge result.

Looking at the `DataFactory` snippet `null` values in `$second` currently are interpreted as "keep the corresponding value of `$first`". But how do I carry along another flag for each field indicating what fields should be set to `null` in the resulting object, in a clean way, and without messing with the data class too much?

Comment: Is the NO UPDATE "flag" akin to the usage of "pristine" when considering html forms? In other words (just to make sure I understand) you'd like to differentiate between an untouched property and one that has been "destroyed"?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's not exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll update my question with some more info. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp, why do you need "to be able to distinguish between a request for either a NO UPDATE operation or an UNSET operation"? What will you use such knowledge for?

Comment: @sevavietl Within my current `merge` implementation there is no way that any property of the returned object has a `null` value if either of the corresponding source values is not `null`. I'm aiming for some extended implementation that allows me to determine whether to set a property to null explicitly inside the returned object. This will require a change of approach from the current `merge` function – and that's fine – but I'm not entirely sure about the most clean/minimal way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has no way to differentiate between unassigned and null variables. 
This makes it pretty unavoidable to keep track of which properties should be overwritten.

I see that you have two concerns:

- Keeping `Data` immutable
- Keeping the interface of `Data` clean (e.g. enforcing strict types)

One of the simplest datastructures that is able to track "defined" and "undefined" properties is an `\stdClass` object (but an array is perfectly fine too).
By moving the `merge()` method into the `Data` class you will be able to hide any implementation details - keeping the interface clean.

An implementation might look something like this:

```php
final class Data {

    /** @var \stdClass */
    protected $props;

    // Avoid direct instantiation, use ::create() instead
    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->props = new \stdClass();
    }

    // Fluent interface
    public static function create(): Data
    {
        return new self();
    }

    // Enforce immutability
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->props = clone $this->props;
    }

    public function withSomeNumber(?int $someNumber): Data
    {
        $d = clone $this;
        $d->props->someNumber = $someNumber;
        return $d;
    }

    public function withSomeString(?string $someString): Data
    {
        $d = clone $this;
        $d->props->someString = $someString;
        return $d;
    }

    public function getSomeNumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->props->someNumber ?? null;
    }

    public function getSomeString(): ?string
    {
        return $this->props->someString ?? null;
    }

    public static function merge(...$dataObjects): Data
    {
        $final = new self();

        foreach ($dataObjects as $data) {
            $final->props = (object) array_merge((array) $final->props, (array) $data->props);
        }

        return $final;
    }
}


$first = Data::create()
    ->withSomeNumber(42)
    ->withSomeString('foo');

// Overwrite both someNumber and someString by assigning null
$second = Data::create()
    ->withSomeNumber(null)
    ->withSomeString(null);

// Overwrite "someString" only
$third = Data::create()
    ->withSomeString('bar');

$merged = Data::merge($first, $second, $third); // Only "someString" property is set to "bar"
var_dump($merged->getSomeString()); // "bar"
```

Comment: This definitely solves the problem I described here. In reality however the `Data` classes are decoratable and composable in a recursive data tree managed through factories. That's why I can not extend too much on the interfaces and implementations of data. Also, the data objects must be free of additional state. Thanks anyway for your answer! +1